# JSON parsing in Haskell: Fail on malformed value

Tags: json, parsing, haskell

I have a record I want to parse from JSON:

```
data ArticleInfo = ArticleInfo {
    author :: String,
    title :: String,
    pubDate :: Day
} deriving (Show, Eq)

instance FromJSON ArticleInfo where
    parseJSON (Object value) = ArticleInfo <$>
        value .: "author" <*>
        value .: "title" <*>
        liftM parsePubDate (value .: "pubDate")
    parseJSON _ = mzero

parsePubDate :: String -> Day
parsePubDate = parseTimeOrError True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%-m-%-d"

parseArticleInfo :: String -> Maybe ArticleInfo
parseArticleInfo source = Data.Yaml.decode (pack source)
```

This works, but crashes on malformed dates that don’t fit the `"%Y-%-m-%-d"` format specifier. The parser specification is above my head at the moment – what do I write there to make the `ArticleInfo` parser return `Nothing` when encountering such dates?

(I know I should start by replacing `parseTimeOrError` with `parseTime`, but that’s about it. And even `parseTime` is deprecated, telling me to use `parseTimeM` whose signature I don’t understand yet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re okay with making the whole parser fail if there’s an invalid date, you can just thread that in without too much hassle:

```
parseJSON (Object value) = ArticleInfo <$>
    value .: "author" <*>
    value .: "title" <*>
    (value .: "pubDate" >>= parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%-m-%-d")
```

If, instead, you want a parser for `Maybe ArticleInfo` (which I thought at first, but now realize you probably don’t want), read on…

---

First off, if you want to be parsing a `Maybe ArticleInfo`, your `FromJSON` instance is going to need to be for a `Maybe ArticleInfo`, not an `ArticleInfo`. (Doing this will require the language extension `FlexibleInstances`.) Secondly, you are going to need to change your `parsePubDate` to return a `Maybe Day` as well, and replace `parseTimeOrError` with `parseTimeM`. (Indeed, when `parseTimeM` is specialized with `m ~ Monad`, `parseTimeM` functions identically to the deprecated `parseTime`.)

Then things get a little more complicated. Somewhat verbosely, you could do:

```
parseJSON (Object value) = (\a t pd -> ArticleInfo a t <$> pd) <$>
    value .: "author" <*>
    value .: "title" <*>
    liftM parsePubDate (value .: "pubDate")
```

…but that’s a little repetitive and isn’t a very ‘nice’ solution. You could alternatively use the [`MaybeT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#t:MaybeT) monad transformer, which might be a bit nicer:

```
parseJSON (Object value) =
  runMaybeT $ ArticleInfo <$> lift (value .: "author")
                          <*> lift (value .: "title")
                          <*> (MaybeT $ parsePubDate <$> value .: "pubDate")
```

Also, all this makes `Data.Yaml.decode (pack source)` return a `Maybe (Maybe ArticleInfo)`. You can use `join` to fold the `Maybe`s together.

Comment: Thank you! How do I write the `FromJSON` instance for `Maybe ArticleInfo`? Plain `instance FromJSON Mayb ArticleInfo` doesn’t work, and neither does `instance FromJSON (Maybe ArticleInfo)`. I feel like an idiot haggling with the compiler like this, but I’d like to get it working and try to grok it afterwards.

Comment: @zoul: I think I was having a little tunnel-vision trying to make `FromJSON (Maybe ArticleInfo)` do what you wanted it to do, where instead you would be okay with the parser just failing and `decode` returning `Nothing`. In that case, just follow the steps before the horizontal line. Otherwise, if you do want to get `instance FromJSON (Maybe ArticleInfo)` working, you’ll need to (a) enable the `FlexibleInstances` syntax extension, (b) add a `join $` to your `parseArticleInfo` definition, and (c) make sure you’re using the most recent revision (I had an error in a previous revision).

Comment: Failing the whole parser is what I was after, now it works. Much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical use of the `Maybe` monad.  It's not that obvious to a beginner, but once you grok monads it becomes second nature.

```
parsePubDate :: String -> Maybe Day
parsePubDate = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%-m-%-d"
```

Comment: But this won’t work with the JSON parser, will it? The compiler complains around `liftM`, saying it expects `String -> Day` and gets `String -> Maybe Day` instead. (Maybe the solution is obvious, but as I said, the JSON parser rules are currently too deep for me.)

Comment: My answer's incomplete.  I focused on getting parsePubDate to return a `Maybe Day` without the big parser picture.

Comment: Thank you anyway, this is useful.